# Failure with CodeIgniter coming from hosting to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, migration, localhost

I've received a project written with this framework and now I want to work it on localhost but I can't view correctly with my xammp.
I already changed base_url in application/config/database.php and also imported database with mysql. I can view html but I can't view css, javscript and loads application, this is main trouble.
https://github.com/Palen/Visitago.git This is the code.

Thank you

Comment: check if there is console errors.

Comment: No errors:(. I think that problem come from php because it can't load applications, for exemple first line on my firefox. load->view('uc_webparts/header_home');?>

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firebug and see "Net" tab.

Check path for each html/js/css request.

Comment: I can't see anything.. because my <head> is empty. <html>
<head></head>
<body>
load->view('uc_webparts/header_home');?>
<div id="background-img">
<div class="franja">
<div id="content2">
load->view('uc_webparts/footer_home');?>
</body>
</html>